# How to show $\sum_{n=0}^{q-1} ne^{2\pi i\frac{p}{q} n^2 } = -\frac{q}{2} $ a connection between Quadratic Gauss Sums and Cesaro Summation

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, fourier-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It can be shown that if $q \equiv 2 \mod 4 $  and $(p,q) = 1$ then

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}  = 0 $$

By the theory of [Quadratic Gauss Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) which is intimately tied to [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

I am interested in proving the related observation: where again if $(p,q) = 1$ and $q \equiv 2 \mod 4$ then

$$ \frac{1}{q} \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} (q - n) e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}  = \frac{1}{2} $$

I have been able to verify this for the first $50$ such natural numbers $q$.

The following simplifications can be observed:

$$ \frac{1}{q} \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} (q - n) e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}  =  \sum_{n=0}^{q-1}  e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}  - \frac{1}{q} \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} n e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}  
 = 0 - \frac{1}{q} \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} n e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2} $$

So the theorem we really want to show is that if $q \equiv 2 \mod 4$ and $(p,q) =1$ then:

$$  \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} n e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q} n^2}= -\frac{q}{2} $$

### Motivation:

This sum is motivated by looking at certain divergent series such as

$$ 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 .... = \frac{1}{2} \ (\mathcal{C}) $$

Where the $(\mathcal{C})$ indicates an assignment and not a literal equality. Whenever a divergent series $\sum a_n $  has the property that $a_n$ has a finite period $p$ and $\sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} a_k = 0 $  then [Cesaro Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)  assigns the following divergent sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k =  \frac{1}{p}  \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}  (p-k)a_k  $$

So, in effect I am also asking why the Cesaro Summation of square powers of the "$q \equiv 2 \mod 4$"th roots of unity is always equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. There are some deep reasons involving the theta functions why this ought to be true [per this answer of Jorge Zuniga](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403882/divergent-series-summation-beyond-natural-boundaries) but this looks like it could tractable using the same set of techniques that prove the original Quadratic Gauss Sum Results.

Comment: Note that $1-1+1-1+1\pm ...=\frac{1}{2}$ does not actually hold ! This is only an assignment , not the usual sum. It is clear from the post that you do not mean that , but nevertheless do not write it down this way.

Comment: In the spirit of $(\mathcal{R} )$ from Ramanujan summation i've added a $\mathcal(C)$  for Cesaro to be clear its not a typical equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{q/2-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}+\sum_{n=q/2+1}^{q-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}+\frac{q}{2}e^{\pi i \frac{pq}{2}}$.

Since $\frac{q}{2}$ is odd, the last term is equal to $-\frac{q}{2}$. Also,

$\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}=-\frac{q}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{q/2-1}{\left(ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} +(q-n)e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}(n-q)^2}\right)}$.

To simplify the last exponential term:

$e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}(n-q)^2}=e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}\times e^{2\pi i pq} \times e^{-4\pi i np}=e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}$.

Substituting:

$\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}{ne^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2}}=-\frac{q}{2}+q\sum_{n=1}^{q/2-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} }=-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{q/2-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} } + \sum_{n=q/2+1}^{q-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} } \right) $

$= -\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} } - e^{\pi i \frac{pq}{2}} \right) = -\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} } +1 \right) = -\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}{e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}n^2} } \right) = -\frac{q}{2}$